# How to remove item in GDCM

Tags: c++, dicom, gdcm

I am trying to remove complete branches (PATIENT, STUDY) from a DICOMDIR file.

Why does the class SequenceOfItems only has a "AddItem(item)" function and a "Clear()" function which removes all items, but no "RemoveItem(item)" function.

How do I remove items from a sequence?
Is this possible at all?
Is there an example for this somewhere?

Comment: good point, please fill in a bug report !

Comment: Is there any workaround?

Comment: It is now logged as bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/gdcm/bugs/311/

Answer (score 0):

There is now a function:

```
bool gdcm::SequenceOfItems::RemoveItemByIndex(const SizeType index)
```

> Remove an Item as specified by its index, if index > size, false is
>   returned Index starts at 1 not 0

see [here](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/2.6/html/classgdcm_1_1SequenceOfItems.xhtml#a4f2628e40941c908f0eef320d1ab0cd2).